# How to GET promotional price using Udemy API?

Tags: php, api

I'm using the Udemy API in php to display the details of their courses on my website.
But, I don't manage to get their promotional prices.
I'm able to retrive all sort of details including the "original price" of each course but I don't find any field with the information of the promotional price.
Can somebody help me please?

The code I'm using to get all information using course ID is the following:

```
function getcourse($id) {
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    $url = "https://www.udemy.com/api-2.0/courses/$id?fields[course]=@all";

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    $c_id = base64_encode('YOUR_CLIENT_ID');
    $c_sid = base64_encode('YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET');

    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,array('X-Udemy-Client-Id: '.$c_id.'','X-Udemy-Client-Secret: '.$c_sid.'',"Authorization: base64 encoded value of client-id:client-secret","Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*"));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);
    $result=curl_exec($ch);
    echo curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT);
    echo curl_getinfo($ch,CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

    curl_close($ch);

    $result = json_decode($result);
    return $result; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This does not appear to be possible with their API, reading the model for the data they only list one item for "price",

https://www.udemy.com/developers/affiliate/models/course/

This leads me to suspect their is one of two possibilities here, 
1. There is a bug in their API that does not return the promo price 
2. This is a deliberate decision on their part to exclude this until the user clicks into the course at which point a "new" price is offered potentially based on if the user is logged into their Udemy account.

Answer (score 0):

```
https://udemy.com/api-2.0/pricing/?course_ids={course_id-1},{course_id-2}, ...
```

The JSON object returned by this endpoint contains information about Udemy courses, specifically focusing on pricing and discount details for a specific course.

The key "courses" holds a nested object where each key represents a course ID. Within each course object, there are various keys that provide specific information. For example, "_class" indicates the type of object, while "price" and "list_price" hold the current and original prices of the course, respectively. The "saving_price" key shows the amount saved through a discount, and "has_discount_saving" confirms if a discount is available. The "campaign" key contains details about ongoing promotional campaigns, including their start and end times.